# Moving and rotating the animation using silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have to create a sample silver-light page that has some user interactive elements like -

1)  A ball and two arrows for left and right directions. 
        Clicking on any arrow should cause the ball to move in that direction.
2)  A drag and drop functionality for some object on the screen.
3)  Clicking on a ball should make it rotate.

Please help me as i m new to this area.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx#Y1587) using xaml

If you have the `Microsoft Blend` then it is very easy to animate

[example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/656/squeeze-ball-animation-in-xaml.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ,but i don't have Microsoft Blend

Comment: then you need to write the code manually.please have a look at the example given above